# asp page crashes when pc shutted down

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crash, vb.net-2010

i was working on my asp page and suddenly the laptop turned off when i turned it on again i open my projects and i started getting several errors such as:

```
value of type 'ASP.upload_content_aspx' cannot be converted to 'System.Web.UI.Page'.    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\homecare_content_web\252a48e8\d856e841\App_Web_3jh3gacb.2.vb

function 'GetTypeHashCode' cannot be declared 'Overrides' because it does not override a function in a base class.  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\homecare_content_web\252a48e8\d856e841\App_Web_3jh3gacb.2.vb

Class 'upload_content_aspx' must implement 'Sub ProcessRequest(context As HttpContext)' for interface 'System.Web.IHttpHandler'.    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\homecare_content_web\252a48e8\d856e841\App_Web_3jh3gacb.2.vb
```

and my aspx.vb page is completely cleared and i'm getting a sequence of binary numbers...
all my code disappeared does anyone know how can i fix this? i can't imaging myself writing the code all over again !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el-khoury,

Please delete all the temporary files of the your computer which is inside C:\ drive then restart visual studio and load your application.

Rememeber clear both
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
and
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp

Comment: Try delete / rename the SUO file. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/df8st53z.aspx for an explanation of what the file is used for.